# Customizing CKEditor to work with clear URL in framework

Tags: javascript, php, url-rewriting, ckeditor, ckfinder

I wrote a small framework with URI structure of lang/domain/controller/method/id an now that I want to use CKFinder integrated with CKEditor I cannot upload and browse server because of address structure? What should I do? To browse the server it uses:

http://localhost/public/admin/style1/plugins/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?CKEditor=abstraction&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=fa

Now I have changed upload and browse address by these:

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('article',
    {
        filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/browser/browse.php',
        filebrowserUploadUrl : '/uploader/upload.php'
    });
```

it shows the images but when I choose them it does not bring it to page and it uploads the file to my image folder but cannot add them or even preview them in body or upload dialogbox. How can I use ckeditor with clear URL?

Comment: i am completely disappointed , any advise is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CKFinder with custom paths**

If you are doing URL rewrite and you expect CKFinder to return URLs with custom paths you can do the following:

You can configure how CKFinder sends URLs to CKEditor in CKFinder's [config.php](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_backends) file in the `backends` section:

```php
$config['backends'][] = array(
    'name'         => 'default',
    'adapter'      => 'local',
    'baseUrl'      => 'http://base/url/ckfinder/will/give/to/ckeditor',
    'root'         => '/path/to/files/on/disk',
    'chmodFiles'   => 0777,
    'chmodFolders' => 0755,
    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8'
);
```

The file path is appended to all URLs and this behavior can't be changed by configuration.

E.g. for `/path/to/files/on/disk/images/picture.png` the returned URL is `http://base/url/ckfinder/will/give/to/ckeditor/images/picture.png`

Alternatively you may add [`'useProxyCommand' => true`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/commands.html#command_proxy) to the backend configuration.

This will change all returned URLs to the form of `http://localhost/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=Proxy&lang=en&type=Files&currentFolder=%2F&hash=9fd5e9f22b8dea6a&fileName=picture.png`, where `http://localhost/core/connector/php/connector.php` is the URL that was used to make the request to get the file's URL.

**Custom integration with a file manager**

If you are implementing your own integration with a file manager check your response from `/uploader/upload.php`. CKEditor expects something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1, 'http://file/url', 'message');</script>`
```

You can find more information in the CKEditor's [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api-section-example-4)

Comment: hi kfazithank you for your answer but it does not solve my problem?what shuld be the adrress?i do not know it must be a folder address?a file that browse the folder of images?what about upload address?could you help me please?